# Checking for SSO session when integrating Auth0 with Google

Tags: single-sign-on, google-authentication, auth0

I'm using Auth0 to achieve SSO with a Google social account, with the following code:

```
this.auth0.getSSOData(function (err, data) {
    if (!isAuthCallback && !err && data.sso) { //Problem line
        // ...
    }
}
```

If I use Auth0 built-in username and password authentication then `data.sso` returns `true`, meaning there is a SSO session active.

However if I use something like Google, for authentication, then `data.sso` returns `false`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correctly enabled the flag *Use Auth0 instead of the IdP to do Single Sign On* and you're still observing this behavior the most likely cause is that you're using Auth0 Developer Keys in the Google social connection.

One of the issues of not using your own keys is that SSO will not function properly; see [Using the Auth0 Developer Keys with Social Connections](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/devkeys) for more information on other constraints.

> Single Sign On will not function properly when using the Auth0 developer keys. The reason for this is that the Auth0 developer applications with all the relevant Identity Providers are configured to call back to the URL `https://login.auth0.com/login/callback` instead of the callback URL for your own tenant, i.e. `https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/login/callback`.
>
> **This results in the SSO cookie not being set on your own tenant domain, so the next time a user authenticates no SSO cookie will be detected**, even if you configured your client to Use Auth0 instead of the Identity Provider to do Single Sign On.

(emphasis is mine)

Comment: Thanks for this, how/where do I specify the keys?

Comment: On the Auth0 Dashboard go to `Connections :: Social` and then select the Google one. On the popup you can change the keys and there's also a link to a [docs page](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/google) that show how to obtain the keys.